# Atmosphere Samples: Can't get chat demo working (atmosphere.js gives 404)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, atmosphere, runjettyrun

I'm trying to get the chat sample running from [atmosphere-samples](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-samples/tree/master/samples/chat)

But I'm getting the following error in the console

```
GET http://localhost:8080/javascript/atmosphere.js 404 (Not Found)
```

When I look at the source for `samples/chat` I can't see atmosphere.js in the code. I'm guessing this file should be coming from one of the atmosphere jars? I was expecting to see it in `src/main/webapp/javascript` but it's not.

I've done the following steps

1. Checkout from git (`git checkout https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-samples.git`)
2. Switch to latest stable branch (`git checkout atmosphere-samples-project-2.0.5`)
3. Import `samples/chat` as an "existing maven project" in eclipse (using m2e plugin)
4. Setup jetty run target (RunJettyRun)
5. Go to `http://localhost:8080/<context>` in a browser.

Note, I see the webapp running, it's just causing javascript errors because of the 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like there's some magic going on in the maven build that's not being replicated in eclipse. I didn't take the time to track down the exact cause but I fixed my problem by copying an appropriate version of `atmosphere.js` from

https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-javascript/blob/master/modules/javascript/src/main/webapp/javascript/atmosphere.js

to `src/main/webapp/javascript`.